# ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.9 - mouse-drag events don´t work in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, internet-explorer-11, arcgis-js-api

I am facing a problem with mouse-drag event form ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.9 in Internet Explorer 11 The code is below:

```
map.on("mouse-drag", zobraudalost);
    
function zobraudalost() {
    alert("test");
}
```

The problem is that, this event doesn't fire at IE 11 (as well as mouse-drag-start, mouse-drag-end). But on the other browsers it works fine (IE9, Firefox, Chrome). The other problem is that other mouse events (click, mouse-move, etc) work fine on IE 11, so the problem is only with the mouse-drags.

Have ever you seen such problem? Do you know if there is some security settings in IE 11 which disable mouse drag events?

Comment: It's is IE, you can expect anything from IE. xD

Comment: Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZaH2f/  (Unfortunately, I can't check it with IE 11, but it works as expected in Firefox and Chrome.)

Comment: Thank You for Your example, but it doesn´t work at IE 11 too. My code works well on Firefox and Chorme, IE 9, but not with IE 11. So the problem is somewhere with IE 11, but don´t know where.

Comment: did u try below added answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, This issue was related to ArcGis JS API version.

**I simply updated the API 3.9 to 3.16** and its started working in IE too.

Here is the running fiddler link to verify.

Fiddler : https://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/j6h00uyt/1/

I verified  in **IE11, chrome and firefox.**

```js
var map;

require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
    map = new Map("map", {
        basemap: "topo",
        center: [-122.45, 37.75], // longitude, latitude
        zoom: 13
    });
    
    map.on("mouse-drag", drag);
    
    function drag() {
        alert("mouse-drag");
    }
});
```

```css
html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/esri/css/esri.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/init.js"></script>


<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems attempting to catch mouseup in IE11. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn304886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the solution I found that worked:

Changed for the drag event you probably want.

```
if(window.PointerEvent) {
  elm.addEventListener("pointermove", foo);
} else if (window.MSPointerEvent) {
  elm.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", foo);
} else {
  elm.addEventListener("mousemove", foo);
}
```

Not your exact solution, but a combination of the above should do it.